How to drag an overlay window tauri
I currently have this titlebar

in my react.js/tauri applicaiton, I placed it inside of a react component so I'm not sure if that matters to what I'm trying to do, I am so frustrated because the drag region just doesn't drag, I can see it but it just isn't dragging here's my config for the window
"windows": [
{
"title": "qadapt-desktop-app",
"width": 800,
"height": 600,
"decorations": true,
"hiddenTitle": true,
"titleBarStyle": "Overlay"
}
],
I am so frustrated, if anyone has any advice on this at all, even a link explaining draggable areas in tauri literally anything I would be so glad, I haven't found a single resource on these and I have no clue if what I'm doing is complete lunacy or not.

I've just killed quite a lot of time on this so providing some answers:
Tauri 1.x

You need to first set the permissions in tauri.conf.json
https://tauri.app/v1/api/config/#windowallowlistconfig

Enable startDragging

Then create a div and add an attribute data-tauri-drag-region:


<div class="my-class" data-tauri-drag-region >My custom TitleBar</div>

Now you can drag the window by that region
Tauri 2.x

You also need to enable the startDragging in your configs.
Here you need to go to the capabilities files. https://v2.tauri.app/security/capabilities/
In permission add core:window:allow-start-dragging or just window:allow-start-dragging
Create the same div

<div class="my-class" data-tauri-drag-region >My custom TitleBar</div>

And you should have a draggable area.
Hope this helps!

And if you double click, can maxsize or normal the window. but text be selected. disable it <div class="my-class" data-tauri-drag-region style="user- select:none;">Title</div>, or for tailwind <div class="my-class select-none" data-tauri-drag-region >Title</div>

This is the simplest way I got it to work in TauriV2:
// tauri.conf.json
{
  // ...
  "app": {
    "security": {
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "identifier": "draggable-window",
          "windows": [
            "*"
          ],
          "permissions": [
            "core:window:allow-start-dragging"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}

Then you can add a custom draggable region anywhere in your app:
<div data-tauri-drag-region>Drag me!</div>


Tauri 1.x
Set fileDropEnabled to false in tauri.config.json:
  "app": {
    "windows": [
      {
        "title": "Your App",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 1024,
        "resizable": true,
        "fullscreen": false,
        "fileDropEnabled": false // <--
      }
    ]
  }

Tauri 2.x
Set dragDropEnabled to false in tauri.config.json:
  "app": {
    "windows": [
      {
        "title": "Your App",
        "width": 1280,
        "height": 1024,
        "resizable": true,
        "fullscreen": false,
        "dragDropEnabled": false // <--
      }
    ]
  }

